# simple_form: disable form without adding disabled: true or readonly: true to every input

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails, forms, simple-form, disabled-input

I have a large *simple_form* form with fields that need to be *enabled* or *disabled* depending upon where the form's partial gets loaded.

My question is:   **how do you *disable every form input* quickly** using simple_form helpers / wrappers?

[Simple Form's documentation](http://www.rubydoc.info/github/plataformatec/simple_form/master/frames) explains how `disabled: true` can be used to disable a *single input field*:

```
<%= simple_form_for @user do |f| %>
  <%= f.input :username, disabled: true %>
  <%= f.button :submit %>
<% end %>
```

But the documentation is less clear on how I can *disable an entire form* via simple_form helpers without needing to repeat `disabled: true` on *literally every form input.*

I tried passing `disabled: true` and `readonly: true` to simple_form's `:wrapper_mappings` option, but that isn't working.

---

#### Example Code:

I load the form via a partial to define simple_form display variables.  This works:

```
#user/show.html.erb:
<%= render partial: 'shared/form', locals: {questionnaire: @questionnaire, readonly_state: true, disabled_state: true, bootstrap_form_class: 'form-horizontal'} %>
```

However, *readonly_state* and *disabled_state* do not work unless I pass them to every form input:

```
# shared/_form.html.erb
<%= simple_form_for(@questionnaire, :html => {:class => bootstrap_form_class}, 

:wrapper_mappings => {check_boxes: :vertical_radio_and_checkboxes, file: :vertical_file_input,
boolean: :vertical_boolean  }) do |f| %>

  <%= f.input :username, disabled: disabled_state, hint: 'You cannot change your username.' %>
  <%= f.input :email, disabled: disabled_state %>
  <%= f.input :city, disabled: disabled_state %>
  <%= f.input :country, disabled: disabled_state %>
  . . .
  <%= f.button :submit %>
<% end %>
```

---

You can quickly see how repetitious this gets with a large form.

### How do I toggle *disable* and *readonly* form attributes quickly across an entire form using DRY code?

Answer (score 9):

You can create a custom wrapper that disables the input like this:

```
# config/initializers/simple_form.rb
config.wrappers :disabled_form do |b|
  b.use :input, disabled: true, readonly: true
end
```

And in the form use:

```
<%= simple_form_for @model, wrapper: :disabled_form %>
  <%= f.input :field %>
  ...
<% end %>
```

Depending on the amount of different inputs in the form, you might need to create more custom wrappers and use a `wrapper_mapping` in the disabled form.

Answer (score 8):

Funny:

```
<%= f.input :username, disabled: true %>
```

Generated 'disabled' class for element.

```
<%= f.input :username, input_html: {disabled: true} %>
```

Don't do this :)

But you can do these:

```
<%= f.input :username, input_html: {readonly: :true} %>
```

or

```
<%= f.input :username, input_html: {disabled: :true} %>
```

Where (unlike readonly) the cursor changes to 🛇

Answer (score 6):

Just a suggestion, you can achieve the behaviour using jquery by setting `$('.form input').prop('disabled', true);` where `form` is your form class.

Answer (score 1):

You can use CSS to mimic the disabled property.
Just create the class and add it conditionally.

```
.disable {
  background: #f2f2f2;
  pointer-events:none;
}
```

Comment: Compared to the `disabled` attribute, this inputs will be submitted and will take part in client-side form validation.